# onServiceConnected() not called

Tags: android, android-service

I have a problem with using a background service.
I am using the service from 2 activities.

The first activity starts the `Service` with `startService(intent)` and the binds to it with `bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

This works perfectly and I can send a `Message` in `onServiceConnected()`.

The second activity only binds to the `Service` (since it's already started), again using `bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

Now here is my problem:
In the second activity I have a `Button` which should use the service when I press it.
However, the `onServiceConnected()` is never called in this activity, so I can not get the binder to create a `Messenger` to send a `Message` to the server.

Does anyone know when `onServiceConnected()` is called exactly, or what it is possibly waiting for?
Or maybe something else to fix this problem?

**EDIT:** `bindService` returns false, what could cause this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `bindService` should return `false` if you want `onRebind` to be called after the first binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onServiceConnected never called after bindService method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486692/onserviceconnected-never-called-after-bindservice-method)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After some more research, I discovered this is a known issue in Android.

The second activity I was talking about was an activity which is used as content within a `TabActivity`.

The way to fix this was to call `bindService(...)` on the application context, instead of on the activity context using `getApplicationContext().bindService(...)`

Comment: Hi there, I have the same problem. Could you explain the remedy a little bit more? If possible could you look at my code here and tell me what should be changed? Thank you so much. This error is driving me insane for a day.

My code: http://ideone.com/cV5BJa

Comment: Could you explain me why we need using getApplicationContext().bindService not bindService?
bindService works in my one activity but not working in my another activity (getApplicationContext().bindService works). It's very strange.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was facing and it makes a lot of sense to use application context rather than activity context. It solved my issue! Thanks man!!

Answer (score 38):

You need to add:

`<service android:name="package.path.to.your.service.class" android:enabled="true"></service>`

in the Android manifest file.

Comment: for me, it no need .class

Comment: is very very import add package + name in manifest  package.path.to.your.service.class

Comment: I met this problem because I merged two projects into one, and forgot to add the service declaration into main manifest file. It's annoying that Android didn't give any prompt about this.

Answer (score 10):

It happened to me just now.
Don't forget to instantiate your `binder` class before the `onbind` return.
Silly mistake, but it happens. hopefully this will help someone in the future.

```
private YourBinder thisBinder;

oncreate
{
  thisBinder = new YourBinder(); //don't forget this.
}


public class YourBinder extends Binder
{

}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
  return thisBinder;
}
```

Comment: Came from the future, that helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Add bind in manifest..

```
 <service
            android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

</service>
```

MyAccessibilityService your service name.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me

Instead of

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

I used

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

Comment: It even works with a new Binder() if you don't need a specific implementation

Answer (score 0):

I was xmarian and had the same problem and later found that i have not given proper name to that service .  So the service name should be given name attribute. Which I suppose the xmarian compiler does the same thing make that entry in Android XML.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I had forgotten to instantiate the binder inside the service and so onBind returned null.
I had this:

```
    private ServiceBinder mServiceBinder;
```

instead of this:

```
    private ServiceBinder mServiceBinder = new ServiceBinder();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<service
            android:name="com.app.triad.tseacro.services.LocationUpdatesService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```