# OnServiceConnected is not called

Tags: android, service, bind, serviceconnection, bindservice

This is my ServiceConnection:

```
   private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        Log.i("","onServiceConnected TRUE");
        locationService = ((LocationService.ServiceBinder)service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        Log.i("","onServiceConnected TRUE DISCONNECT");
        locationService = null;
    }
};
```

This is never entered.
I call it like this:

```
  void doBindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

From my ApplicationClass onCreate:

```
  Intent i= new Intent(PSLocationCenter.this, LocationService.class);
    startService(i);
    doBindService();
```

And I have this in the Manifest:

```
   <service android:name=".services.LocationService" android:enabled="true"/>
```

Am i trying to bind it wrongly? Why is it not called.

Comment: and will it start without it?

Comment: Still doesn't work if I take out startService

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but maybe it will help someone.
This answer makes sense: [using getApplicatinContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875131/onserviceconnected-not-called)
I must admit it hasn't worked for me yet, and I'm still looking, but you seem to have the same problem he had.