# onserviceconnected never called: android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

How to start a service on its own?? 
I dont want to start the service from another activity.but i want to bind to the service to the activity..
my problem is exactly as described in this link.
[onServiceConnected never called after bindService method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486692/onserviceconnected-never-called-after-bindservice-method)
i.e my onserviceconnected is never called.

```
Messenger mService = null;
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            mService = new Messenger(service);
            Log.d("IMSLogging", "inside onServiceConnected");
        }
```

from oncreate of my activity i am calling bindService.but i am getting a nullpointerexception when i am doing mService.send(msg); from oncreate.(after the bindService is called, of course.) though bindService is returning true.,

Comment: I believe i have posted the code. The problem is mService stays null even after i call bindservice from oncreate method.also the log.d that i have mentioned in the code is never found in the logs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `mService.send()` until **after** you get the `onServiceConnected()` callback. That means you can't do both `bindService()` and `mService.send()` in `onCreate()`. You need to move the `mService.send()` call into either `onResume()` or into `onServiceConnected()` or somewhere else.

Comment: Even I was thinking of the same.But all these happens onclick of a button.and the setonClickListener and onCreate and all. they are defined in onCreate only. Do I then shift every thing ???

Comment: You can post your code and I can help you some more. However, you should be able to setup your UI in `onCreate()`, you just cannot use the service until **after** the `onServiceConnected()` callback comes back.

Comment: Hey,Thanks, i got it solved. Actually i was calling the onBind within the onclick listener.Thanks. :)

Comment: @scooby: Whats the issue calling onBind within the onclick listener?