# Android Studio Services onServiceConnected() never called while onBind() is

Tags: android, android-studio, service

In my app, I am using bound services. However, while running the code, I start the service and bind to it(OnBind() method works), but afterwards OnStartService() is never called, and my service is equal to null.

Here is my service code:

```
public class MyService extends Service{

boolean toExit = false;
boolean isThreatDetectionOn;

boolean isDanger = false;
int counter;

class MyServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService()
    {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("Bind", "thats good");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stop();

    super.onDestroy();

}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    isThreatDetectionOn = true;




    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            start();
        }
    }).start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

start() and stop() are method that run in the service that start generating random  numbers and stop generating random numbers, respectively.

Here is the  bind/unbind code for the service:

```
private MyService ListeningService;
private boolean isServiceBound = false;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection;


bindService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    bindService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Log.i("Great","Button Bind Clicked");
            if(serviceConnection == null)
            {
                Log.i("Great","Service Connection is Null");
                serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
                    @Override
                    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
                        MyService.MyServiceBinder myBinder = (MyService.MyServiceBinder)iBinder;
                        listeningService = myBinder.getService();
                        isServiceBound = true;
                        Log.i("Yes", "Service Connected");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
                        isServiceBound = false;
                        Log.i("No", "Service DisConnected");
                    }
                };
            }

            bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
        });

    unbindService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    unbindService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isServiceBound)
            {
                unbindService(serviceConnection);
                isServiceBound = false;
                Log.i("No", "Service DisConnected");
            }
        }
    });
```

Even after onBind() is called(in the logs it says "Bind:thats good") isServiceBound still remains false when it should now become true because the service is now connected.

Comment: You have to return `Binder` object - you're returning `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onServiceConnected never called after bindService method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486692/onserviceconnected-never-called-after-bindservice-method)